# Clock Tower lockdown glitch?

Tags: pc, batman-arkham-knight

I'm nearing the end of the game, where you clear out the Clock Tower area of all the bad guys, and had Batman lock down the system. The room goes back to the way it was, I grapple up to the roof, but nothing happens.

Location marker seems to keep telling me to go back into the room, as far as I can tell. Even went to the lower levels where I cleared out the militia, but still can't find anything.

Am I missing something? Did the game glitch? All guides I've looked at seem to indicate all I need to do is lock down the mainframe, and that's it.

Why aren't I progressing to the next part of the level?

Comment: You have to use one of the computers at the lower floors.  That will restore the systems.

Comment: @JeffMercado Yeah, I figured it out about 30 minutes after posting this. Took a break and came back to it. Found a better video on YouTube that showed where the right console is. Map wasn't very good at indicating that. I'll delete this question most likely.

Answer (score 2):

Found out that it's a computer terminal on the third floor of the space bellow Oracle's loft in the Clock Tower, so it was on a floor you clear enemies from. Once you activate it you should get the Lamb to the Slaughter mission immediately.